# Customize Maven command when deploying to Heroku

Tags: maven, heroku, deployment

We generate documentation from our tests with Spring REST Docs. When deploying the application to Heroku, by default tests are skipped, as I can see clearly in the logs:

```
-----> Java app detected
-----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
-----> Installing Maven 3.3.9... done
-----> Executing: mvn -DskipTests clean dependency:list install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
```

How can I customize the Maven command that is executed by Heroku?

Comment: have you tried putting `<maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip>` property in your pom?

Comment: Thanks for the tip of specifying this in your ``pom.xml``. I ended up configuring the Maven Surefire Plugin. See my answer for more information. All the best!

Answer (score 3):

After a day of searching, I found two possible ways to enable tests for the Heroku build:

1. Configure [Maven Surefire Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) in your `pom.xml`
2. Customize [Heroku Java Buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java)

#### Maven Surefire Plugin

Configuration in your `pom.xml` overrides command-line arguments when your Maven process is started.

You can undo `-DskipTests` by disabling `skipTests` in the Maven Surefire Plugin configuration as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

> Please note that Heroku adds environment variables when running Maven. Make sure you use an in-memory database when running in the Spring `test`profile, otherwise the build will fail.
>
> In my case, I use Flyway for database migrations. For some weird reason, regardless the `spring.datasource.url` in my `application-test.yml`, Flyway used the environment variable value. If you have the same issue, please note that you can override them too with the `argLine` configuration property of the Maven Surefire Plugin.
>
> `<argLine>-DDATABASE_URL=jdbc:h2:mem:questflair -DJDBC_DATABASE_URL=jdbc:h2:mem:questflair -DSPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:h2:mem:questflair</argLine>`

#### Heroku Java Buildpack

According to the Heroku Java Buildpack documentation, you can customize Maven options and goals.

I didn't try this solution, see [Customize Maven](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java#customize-maven) for more information.